# How can we resize a Media Image inserted using Ckeditor5?

Tags: media, wysiwyg

D9.5 - Ckeditor 1 (v5)

We have Media Images and are using Ckeditor's "Insert Media" button in the WYSIWYG but we cannot resize the images.

Is this possible with Media images?

Comment: I don’t think so. This is an open feature request: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3321250

Comment: There is a module for this now: https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_media_resize

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with the patch I built.
There are patches for

- Drupal 9.5x
- Drupal 10.0x
- Drupal 10.1x
- Drupal 11.x Dev

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3359725

Once install patch, then visit text editor configuration page, enable `Use <img> tag for Media Image type` option in Filter settings \ Embed media